# CDI injection of string values from XML / deployment time specification of values

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

In Spring it is possible to define string values (eg: server names, user names, passwords etc.) in an application context XML file. These can be modified per deployment (eg: testing, production etc). Can I do the same in CDI? If not, what is the accepted pattern for handling the deployment time specification of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a portable extension to do that, there isn't anything out of the box for it.